# Close winforms system when closing windows session

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, active-directory

I have a winforms system that uses the same user and password to start windows session using the Active Directory credentials (This to not create a user and password for each system that is made).
What I want to do is that when the user for example closes his windows session or type the Ctrl + Alt + Del keys and select Lock or Switch User at the same time he closes the winforms system and returns the login the next time he logs in windows or unlock your session.

How can I do that?

The system is made in C # using VS2012 professional.
If you need more information, please let me know.

I hope you understand what I'm looking for.

EDITED

I have this code for Lock the session of windows, so I only look for when this event is launched in the current session and send call for closing my system or Form.

```
 [DllImport("user32")]

    public static extern void LockWorkStation();

    LockWorkStation();
```

Comment: The `[Form].FormClosed` event reports the reason why the app is closing in the `e.CloseReason` property of the `FormClosedEventArgs`. If this is what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the ask.

Comment: Locking the workstation doesn't close the running applications. You get a [WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa383828(v=VS.85).aspx) message instead, when the user logs in again.

Comment: I understand, what about this message WM_QUERYENDSESSION?

Comment: That message is sent when the user requests to close the current session, until an app sets the result to to `IntPtr.Zero`. The windowed applications are closed when the session ends.

Comment: You get a `CloseReason.WindowsShutDown` in that case.